# PHP, convert string into UTF-8 and then hexadecimal

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, type-conversion, vcf-vcard

In PHP, I want to convert a string which contains non-ASCII characters into a sequence of hexadecimal numbers which represents the UTF-8 encoding of these characters.  For instance, given this:

```
$text = 'ąćę';
```

I need to produce this:

```
C4=84=C4=87=C4=99
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What are those numbers exactly? What are you ultimately doing with them? You could use `json_encode` on them but you won't get the values you mentioned.

Comment: I took out some irrelevant text, clarified your ultimate goal as I understand it, and made it clear that the string involved is just an example.  Now, we need some more information from you in order to answer the question. 1: Is this [quoted-printable encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) you're going for? 2: There's supposed to be an equals sign before the first C4, yes? 3: What should happen to ASCII characters? (e.g. if the string was `'ącę'` instead, should that come out `=C4=84=63=C4=99`, or `=C4=84c=C4=99`?)

Comment: @mkaatman I didn't check, but I am 99% sure that C4 84 C4 87 C4 99 is the hexadecimal representation of each byte in the UTF-8 encoding of the character sequence `ąćę` (that is, U+0105 U+0107 U+0119).  And the =XX notation looks suspiciously like [MIME quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding to me.

Comment: I'm thinking that the `84` should actually be `85`; you can URL encode the text to check quickly.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is written, and assuming that your text is properly UTF-8 encoded to start with, this should work:

```
$text = 'ąćę';
$result = implode('=', str_split(strtoupper(bin2hex($text)), 2));
```

If your text is not UTF-8, but some other encoding, then you can use

```
$utf8 = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', $yourEncoding);
```

to get it into UTF-8, where `$yourEncoding` is some other character encoding like `'ISO-8859-1'`.

This works because in PHP, strings are just arrays of bytes.  So as long as your text is encoded properly to start with, you don't have to do anything special to treat it as bytes.  In fact, this code will work for any character encoding you want without modification.

Now, if you want to do quoted-printable, then that's another story.  You could try using the function `quoted_printable_encode` (requires PHP 5.3 or higher).